# Pull Data from Specific Excel Cell into ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, excel

I am new to Python and ArcPy, and wish to create a short script that pulls in a value from one specific Excel worksheet cell (namely, A2) and then performs an 'if' statement, whereby if the value of A2 is greater than 1, then a certain text string is returned, but if it is less than or equal to 1, then a different text string is returned.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\MMO_Model_Test\testdata.xlsx"
inputData = "data"
```

I have defined my workspace, and set the relevant worksheet as a variable. I now need to reference the cell 'A2' as part of an 'if' statement. This is probably simple for someone who knows how, but I haven't managed to find a relevant example online.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use the `xlrd` module to read Microsoft Excel files (I think it's limited to .xls files only). To open your spreadsheet and read cell A2, you would use the following:

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook(r"C:\MMO_Model_Test\testdata.xlsx") # may not work with .xlsx file
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0) # opens the first worksheet
val = sh.cell_value(1,0) # index row,col values corresponding to cell A2
# do something with val
```

Documentation for the `xlrd` module is found [here](http://www.python-excel.org/).